# Spark Streaming - Calculating stats from key-value pairs grouped by keys

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Background:
I'm using Spark Streaming to stream events from Kafka which are in the form of comma separated key value pairs
Here is an example of how events are streamed into my spark application.

```
Key1=Value1, Key2=Value2, Key3=Value3, Key4=Value4,responseTime=200
Key1=Value5, Key2=Value6, Key3=Value7, Key4=Value8,responseTime=150
Key1=Value9, Key2=Value10, Key3=Value11, Key4=Value12,responseTime=100
```

**Output**:

I want to calculate different metrics (avg, count etc.) grouped by different keys in the stream for a given batch interval e.g.

1. Average responseTime by Key1, Key2 (responseTime is one of the keys in every event)
2. Count by Key1, Key2

My attempts so far:

```
val stream = KafkaUtils
  .createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
     ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

val pStream = stream.persist()

val events: DStream[String] = pStream.flatMap(_._2.split(","))
val pairs= events.map(data => data.split("=")).map(array => (array(0), array(1)))
// pairs results in tuples of (Key1, Value1), (Key2, Value2) and so on.
```

**Update** - 03/04
The keys Key1, Key2...can arrive out of order in the incoming stream.

Appreciate your inputs / hints.

Comment: Could you provide expected output type and your attempts so far? It is not cleat what you really want.

Comment: @zero323 - Ok, I updated my question with the expected output type and my attempts so far. I'll post the answer if I'm able to get through this.

Comment: Thanks. I formatted this a little.

Comment: You beat me on the update :). I realized after posting that I missed the formatting. Thanks!

Comment: Sure :) Do you want to compute stats per window? If so have you considered using `DataFrames`?

Comment: Hmm..haven't considered DataFrames. I want the stats to be calculated per streaming batch interval (at least, for now). E.g. rolled up stats per sec from the incoming raw events. Therefore, my streaming batch interval is set to 1 sec.

Comment: Could you edit your subject line? It has nothing really to do with your actual question

Comment: @The Archetypal Paul - makes sense. done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is something like this:

- create a case class representing each record so we don't have deal with tuples:

  ```
  case class Record(
    key1: String, key2: String, key3: String, key4: String, rt: Double)
  ```
- use regexp to parse record and drop malformed entries:

  ```
  import scala.util.matching.Regex

  val recordPattern = new Regex(
    "^Key1=(.*?), ?Key2=(.*?), ?Key3=(.*?), ?Key4=(.*?), ?" ++
    "responseTime=(0-9+)$"
  )

  val records = pStream.map {
    case recordPattern(key1, key2, key3, key4, rt) =>
      Some(Record(key1, key2, key3, key4, rt.toDouble))
    case _ => None
  }.flatMap(x => x) // Drop malformed
  ```
- reshape data to key-value pairs:

  ```
  val pairs = records.map(r => ((r.key1, r.key2), r.rt))
  ```
- create a partitioner and use `StatCounter` to aggregate statistics:

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter
  import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner

  val paritioner: HashPartitioner = ???

  pairs.combineByKey[StatCounter](
    StatCounter(_), _ merge _,  _ merge _, paritioner
  )
  ```
- extract fields of interest:

  ```
  stats.mapValues(s => (s.count, s.mean))
  ```

You can also try something like this for unordered data although I would strongly suggest fixing things upstream:

```
val kvPattern = "(\\w+)=(\\w+)".r
val pairs = pStream.map(line => {
  val kvs = kvPattern.findAllMatchIn(line)
    .map(m => (m.group(1), m.group(2))).toMap

  // This will discard any malformed lines
  // (lack of key1, key2, lack or invalid format of responseTime)
  Try((
    (kvs("Key1"), kvs("Key2")), 
    kvs("responseTime").toDouble
  ))

}).flatMap(_.toOption)
```

and proceed as before.

Comment: Thanks +1. This might work. Only caveat, which I probably forgot to mention in my question is the key1, key2 may not necessarily be in the same sequence everytime, so the regex won't match. I was thinking of applying more generic solution, hence to go by the key value tuple and thus do lookups on the key1, key2 on them as configured. Thoughts ?

Comment: also great tip on using StatsCounter.

Comment: Then you'll have to parse this other way. Extracting key-value pairs into a `Map` should do just fine.

Comment: mind posting a quick code snippet on how to tie this all together? will be much appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: To bring more clarity, basically there are 2 main things : 1) the keys can come out of order 2) the additional grouping by keys will need to be added without much code changes. That's the reason, I was a bit hesitant to go by the case class approach.

Comment: There is really no quick fix here. You can try something similar to the edit but a lot depends on the context and requirements.

Comment: you saved me a heck of a time.  You're a Spark guru!! Wish I could buy you a coffee / beer :) The approach in the edit definitely works but had to modify to suit my requirement#2 ( i.e. the additional grouping by keys will need to be added without much code changes) to dynamically create tuples and also updated regex to cover more cases. I will add my edits soon, in case it turns out useful for someone.

Comment: This was unexpected. Thanks @Hiten.

Comment: This was just a way of saying a Huge thanks to you for your well thought answer! I wish I could offer more bounty points to you but for sure in future once I collect more reputation points on SO :)